# How to debug chained API calls

Tags: api, chaining

How can I get back a dump of the full param array when a chained api call fails, so that I can see what values are coming back from the previous call and going into the chained call (and thus better troubleshoot cause of failure)?

I know that I can add the "debug" param into the array, but I can't seem to read the trace in a way that tells me what $value was returned from the previous call and inserted to the chained call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use try/catch and the CiviCRM_API3_Exception class to get more information. It would be something like this:

```
try{
  $result = civicrm_api3('contact', 'get', $params);
}
catch (CiviCRM_API3_Exception $e) {
  // handle error here
  $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
  $errorCode = $e->getErrorCode();
  $errorData = $e->getExtraParams();
  return array('error' => $errorMessage, 'error_code' => $errorCode, 'error_data' => $errorData);
}
```

The getExtraParams method should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be addressing question of a chained call, and getting the debug info from between the calls.